# How can I map a nullable enum in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have been unable to persist a nullable enum using NHibernate with Fluent NHibernate configuration. NHibernate attempts to save a string representation of the enum and I get the error

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting the 
nvarchar value 'VGS' to data type tinyint.
```

The property is defined as

```
public virtual CostContributor? ReplacementContributor { get; private set; }
```

and the mapping is

```
Map(x => x.ReplacementContributor).CustomTypeIs(typeof(CostContributor?));
```

I've tried every combination of CustomTypeIs and CustomSqlTypeIs, including substituting int? or byte? for CostContributor?, but nothing has worked. It works fine if I make it a non-nullable type.

Is it possible to map a nullable enum in NHibernate? Or is this a bug or unsupported feature in NHibernate?

If I can't make this work I'm going to add an Undefined value to my enum as a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a [bug and it's been fixed](http://code.google.com/p/fluent-nhibernate/issues/detail?id=168).

Comment: The link provided here is dead, but the question has been answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881971/fluent-nhibernate-mapping-nullable-enum

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do it properly but here's another workaround:

Add a class called CostContributorEntity. The class will have only property: ID, of type CostContributor. You don't need to create a real table unless you want to.

In the consuming classes change ReplacementContributor to be of type CostContributorEntity, and map it as **References**(x => x.ReplacementContributor);

Use session.Load(CostContributor.Blahblah1) to create instance of CostContributorEntity you can assign to ReplacementContributor.